# iPhone rolling page (maps application style)

Tags: iphone, maps

How can I implement a "rolling page" effect like the one in iPhone maps application?

(The effect when the user tap the lower right button in the page here: http://artbeatme.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/bixi_map_1.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to flip to another view, you can use

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self cache:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

it's an undocumented animation transition.  they're not safe to use as apple can change them at any time and/or they will reject your app for using private methods.

read Page 67 from Erica Sadun's iPhone Developer's Cookbook: "Undocumented Animation Types" for more details.  you can also download her sample code from [her site](http://code.google.com/p/cookbooksamples/downloads/list).  what you are looking for is "07c - MapCurl" from "C02 - Views.zip".